# Как заменить фрагмент на фрагмент android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, replace, fragment-transaction

Есть такой XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        >
        <fragment
            android:name="autovesti.auto.Fragment2"
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
        </fragment>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Как правильно заменить fragment 1 на fragment 2? Вот так

```
tran = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tran.replace(R.id.fragment1, new Fragment2());
```

Первый становится прозрачным, и появляется второй.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте так:

1. Удалите фрагмент `autovesti.auto.Fragment2` из xml.
2. Удалённый из `xml` фрагмент (`autovesti.auto.Fragment2`) добавляйте из кода.

   ```
   tran = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
   tran.add(R.id.fragment1, new Fragment2());
   ```
3. Теперь

   ```
   tran = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
   tran.replace(R.id.fragment1, new Fragment2());
   ```

работает корректно.

Comment: Спасибо. Я тут забыл уточнить маленькую вещь, возможно, она и незначительная.  
Я хочу заменить фрагмент через активити на другой фрагмент.  
Подробнее: у меня в фрагменте есть список статей, по нажатию на элемент списка появляется статья полность, т.е. первый фрагмент должен скрыться, а другой появиться!

Comment: Т.е. у вас 2 разных фрагмента? 1 список и 2 статья? Если да, то сначала добавляйте 1-ый фрагмент, а по клику на его пункт, делайте replace на второй фрагмент.