# Переход во фрагмент при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: android-fragment, java, android

Всем добрый вечер, уже какой день мучаюсь с этими фрагментами, все никак не могу реализовать, например, у нас есть активити, на нем расположена кнопка, и при нажатии на нее, сразу же открывается новое окно фрагмент.
Вот в этом приложении так реализовано.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.formul.fizik&hl=ru
Нажимаем и открывается.

**Обновление**

Дело в том, что реализовать переход из одного активити в другое активити, проблем нет, но я никак не пойму, как с помощью фрагментов можно сделать быстрый переход, возьмем тот же справочник, который выше. При нажатии на кнопку, мгновенно открывается содержание определенной темы.

К сожалению ошибка http://joxi.ru/GrqBoweHQnpGmz

Ошибку исправил, но у меня получается при нажатии на фрагмент появляется фрагмент, и кнопки остаются, и я могу нажать еще раз и еще раз на кнопку и так кол-во раз, появится фрагмент.

**Обновление 2**

Я исправил импорт с `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` на `import android.app.Fragment;` - ошибка пропала.

Я создал

```
layout: activity_main и fragment.
Fragment1.class и MainActivity
В Fragment.class я прописал 
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
    }
}
```

А в MainActivity заскринил `http://joxi.ru/1A5J4n9tn0BprE`.
Так же
`fragment.xml http://joxi.ru/Y2LDVWqH9wyJ26
activity_main http://joxi.ru/l2ZYByVHwDKGmJ`

Comment: @Verteletsky, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Verteletsky, а вы уверены, что  лэйауте активити у вас только контейнер, а кнопки все добавлены во фрагмент, коий в onCreate активити добавляется?

Comment: Вот на скриншоте http://joxi.ru/L21Jyajt86j5AX

Comment: @Verteletsky, тут проблема в том, что у вас фрагмент  кнопками в XML указан, а надо его оттуда убрать и добавлять через 

    trans.add(id, frag);

в onCreate activity;

Вот тут посмотрите, я уже отвечал:

[http://hashcode.ru/questions/381523/java-как-заменить-фрагмент-на-фрагмент-android]

Comment: В предыдущем комменте ссылка битая. Вот нормальная: [как-заменить-фрагмент-на-фрагмент-andr‌​oid](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381523/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Принцип тут такой:

1) В разметке активити есть контейнер (FrameLayout, например) с id="yours_id".

2) В активити, при нажатии на кнопку, добавляем фрагмент в контейнер:

```
Fragment yoursFragment=new YoursFragment();
FragmentTransaction trans=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.add(R.id.yours_id, yoursFragment);
trans.commit();
```

3) Чтобы всё это работало, вам скорее всего придётся переделать всю логику активити под фрагменты (т.е. кнопка, запускающая открытие фрагмента тоже должна быть во фрагменте, и оба фрагмента должны быть в одном контейнере);

**Обновление**

Если же вы хотите, чтобы на экране "исчезали" все кнопки и 1-й фрагмент появлялся поверх всего, то вам надо сами кнопки встроить в другой фрагмент. Далее при старте активити добавлять фрагмент с кнопками (в FrameLayout), а при нажатии на одну из них делать

```
trans.replace(R.id.yours_id, frag1);
trans.addToBackStack(null);
trans.commit();
```

Так у вас будет всё содержимое с экрана по нажатию кнопки заменяться на frag1, а при нажатии на кнопку "назад" показываться опять фрагмент с кнопками.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сейчас буду пробовать!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, trans.add(R.id.yours_id, yoursFragment); подчеркивается

Comment: @Verteletsky, если вы наведёте курсор на подчёркивания, то должна появиться подсказка об ошибке.
Скорее всего вы контейнер не сделали в XML или не дали ему id или не тот id пишете.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,я исправил импорт с import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; на import android.app.Fragment; , ошибка пропала, 
Я создал
layout: activity_main и fragment.
Fragment1.class и MainActivity
В Fragment.class я прописал 
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
    }
}
а в MainActivity заскринил http://joxi.ru/1A5J4n9tn0BprE
Так же fragment.xml http://joxi.ru/Y2LDVWqH9wyJ26
activity_main http://joxi.ru/l2ZYByVHwDKGm

Comment: @Verteletsky, ну, вот теперь у вас при нажатии на 1-ую кнопку в FrameLayout должен добавляться Fragment1.

Comment: @Verteletsky, Обновил ответ

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Вы гений! Именно это мне и нужно! Сейчас буду пытаться это сделать!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
Подскажите, пожалуйста, а каким образом в этот фрагмент с кнопками передать `FragmentTransaction`, чтобы вызывать его методы при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: @Dimio, скорее всего передавать ничего не нужно. Во фрагменте можно новую транзакцию создать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
Спасибо, так и поступил, хотя что-то во мне противилось этому подходу (но я не знаком с android-разработкой).
Раз он подкрепляется компетентным мнением - им и воспользуюсь спокойно.

Comment: Тут есть несколько нюансов. Надо не перепутать FragmentManager актвити и фрагмента. Также надо внимательно следить за используемым ID контейнера, в который фрагмент добавляется. Ну и саму навигацию (смену экранов) лучше вынести в какую-то абстракцию. Например Moxy библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер, [[@Verteletsky](/users/26232/verteletsky)](/users/26232/verteletsky)!

Я понял Ваш вопрос и могу посоветовать почитать следующие статьи:

1. [Android 3. Fragments. Lifecycle](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/174-urok-104-android-3-fragments-lifecycle.html)
2. [Android 3. Fragments. Динамическая работа](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/175-urok-105-android-3-fragments-dinamicheskaja-rabota.html)
3. [Android 3. Fragments. Взаимодействие с Activity](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html)

и это:

1. [Android 3. Fragments. ListFragment - список](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/179-urok-109-android-3-fragments-listfragment-spisok.html)
2. [Android 3. Fragments. DialogFragment - диалог](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/180-urok-110-android-3-fragments-dialogfragment-dialog.html)

Думаю, если Вам нужно вывести небольшое окно на экран, то Вам нужна ссылка №5. Если фрагмент на весь экран, то ознакомьтесь со ссылками №1-3.

Ссылки ведут на уроки с сайта [startandroid.ru](http://startandroid.ru/). Рекомендую добавить данный сайт себе в закладки, в будущем пригодится. 
  P.S.: рекомендую из личного опыта работы с сайтом. Иногда, конечно, материал подан как-то сжато, но для введения в вопрос и его достаточно.

Comment: @web_alex, Спасибо большое за ответ, но я там уже побывал.

Comment: @Verteletsky, и 5-я ссылка Вам не подходит? Или я неправильно понял вопрос?