# Наложение фрагмента на фрагмент. За добавленным фрагментом виден предыдущий

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

Задача такая: при нажатии на кнопку, нужно попасть в фрагмент.
Вставил код, а он не работает:

Информацию про код брал здесь: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383052/Переход-во-фрагмент-при-нажатии-на-кнопку?rq=1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383052/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83?rq=1)

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = null;


                    mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new sovety_Fragment();
                        mManager.beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)// вот етот код добавил
                                .addToBackStack(null) // вот етот код добавил
                                .commit();
                    }}


    });
```

фрагмент на фрагменте , а нужно что б только `sovety_Fragment`отображались после нажатия

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вашего фрагмента, того, что вы добавляете, прозрачный фон. Просто проставьте ему непрозрачный фон. По умолчанию фон прозрачен.

Comment: Не думаю что "замазывать" старый фрагмент фоном это хорошее решение. Наипрямейший путь к утечкам памяти, ну или как минимум к нерациональному её расходованию.

Comment: @xkor, в данном случае - да, я просто не заметил лишний `add`. Но, бывает, нужно именно через фон скрыть фрагмент на заднем плане. Например если фрагмент сзади  - во `ViewPager`-е и вы не можете его скрыть вызвав `replace` над контейнером `ViewPager`-а

Comment: ну при более менее продуманной архитектуре приложения думаю что не должны возникать проблемы с заменой фрагмента на любом уровне иерархии от текущего.
Это моё ИМХО, но скрытие фрагмента через фон я считаю костылем приемлемым только если этот вариант позволяет решить некую задачу прямо сейчас, более правильная реализация займет более пары часов, а заказчик ультимативно требует что бы всё было здесь и сейчас грозя 10ю казнями египетскими. И то этот вариант обязательно надо будет переписать после удовлетворения заказчика, пока про него все не забыли и он не попал бы в следующий релиз.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>                  .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
>                  .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment) // вот этот код добавил
> ```

Ну так вы два раза фрагмент добавляете, точнее и добавляете и заменяете. Оставьте только replace, тогда предыдущий фрагмент будет заменяться новым. А про непрозрачный фон не слушайте, то что старый фрагмент не видно, это конечно хорошо, но Вам ведь надо что бы его и не было, а то так наплодите невидимых фрагментов, а потом будете удивляться - куда это вся память ушла.

Comment: Можно сказать проще - метод `add()` добавляет в контейнер  к уже существующим фрагментам еще один, отсюда и наложение.  Метод `replace()` заменяет существующий в контейнере фрагмент тем, что указан в параметре метода.