# Фрагменты наслаиваются друг на друга.

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, fragment-transaction

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layoutForFragment = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_for_fragment);   
        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layout_for_fragment,cardStation);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

В методе OnCreate я вставляю фрагмент во FrameLayout. Проблема в том, что при повороте экрана или при вылете с ошибкой фрагменты накладываются друг на друга на одно и то же место.  Как решить проблему ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Наложение фрагмента на фрагмент. За добавленным фрагментом виден предыдущий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480376/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%97%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9). Непринятый ответ - правильный.

Comment: @pavlofff, тут в другом дело - в цели дубля была лишняя операция, а тут просто не проверяется был ли уже фрагмент добавлен

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, вы правы.

Comment: Еще как вариант использовать `.replace` вместо `.add`

Comment: Да, фрагмент не будет наслаиваться на предыдущий, но будет лишний раз добавлен, заменив тот, что уже и так есть в памяти FragmentManager-а

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. При повороте экрана активити пересоздаётся.
2. При пересоздании активити система пытается восстановить предыдущее состояние.
3. В предыдущем состоянии в активити добавлен фрагмент и система его восстанавливает, добавляя на экран.
4. После этого выполняется onCreate, где вы добавляете ещё один фрагмент. Итого их у вас (число поворотов экрана)*1

Вам надо просто проверять восстановила ли активити к-л фрагмент, поискав его во FragmentManager по ID контейнера, и, если нет, то добавлять его:

```
cardStation = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.layout_for_fragment);
if (cardStation == null)
{
    cardStation = new CardStation();
    getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_for_fragment, cardStation)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: Есть [еще способ (в самом конце страницы)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=ru#Example) проверять в условии добавления фрагмента `if (savedInstanceState == null)` - при первом запуске активити сохраненное состояние равно null, при поворотах оно инициализируется системой, даже если программист туда ничего не сохранял. Это намного "дешевле" поиска фрагментов в фрагмент-менеджере по ID.

Comment: @pavlofff, да, так тоже можно, но, если фрагмент не на весь экран,а только на часть и добавляется не всегда, а по событию, то это не поможет)