# Переход из фрагмента во фрагмент

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть фрагмент в котором две кнопки, при нажатии на каждую из которых должен осуществляться переход на другой фрагмент. Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383052/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии на вашу кнопку, в первом фрагменте должно произойти что-то подобное, тогда осуществится переход ко второму фрагменту.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // где Fragment_Train - это второй фрагмент
        Fragment Fragment_Train=new Fragment_Train();
        FragmentTransaction trans=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(R.id.container, Fragment_Train);
        trans.commit();

    }
```