# Как заменить один фрагмент другим?

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь заменить один фрагмент другим, через кнопку(btnKf_2) которая находиться в первом фрагменте. Эмулятор запускается, а подмены фрагмента при нажатии кнопки не происходит. Делаю псалтырь, в нем 22 фрагмента и куча кнопок. Использовал action bar в android studio.

```
 public void onClick (View v) {
    frag1 = new Kafuzma1();
    frag2 = new Kafuzma2();
    fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.butKf_2:
            fTrans.replace(R.id.frame_layout,frag2);
            fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        default:
            break;
    }
    fTrans.commit();
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отвечаю на свой вопрос.
СПАСИБО Andrew Goroshko.
Нужно было во фрагмент добавить вот этот код:

```
    Button butKf_2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.butKf_2);
    butKf_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment kaf2 = new Kafuzma2();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, kaf2);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
   });
```

Comment: На вид должно работать. Где описан метод onClick? и вы точно передаете его кнопке через setOnClickListener?

Comment: Наверное в этом и загвоздка. Я делал по примеру из этого сайта, про метод onClick там ничего не было сказано. Я подумал что id кнопки достаточно. А как мне правильно реализовать метод onClick и где его прописать?

Comment: Вы должны тот объект, в котором описан onClick сохранить в переменную, например listener, отдать в кнопку. Находите кнопку на фрагменте через findViewById, и вызываете для нее button.setOnClickListener(listener). Так вы скажете что вот этот вот метод должен вызваться при нажатии на такую-то кнопку. Соответственно, можно разным кнопкам присваивать разные методы

Comment: и еще вопрос - где у вас используется переменная `frag1`, по коду я ее не увидел?

Comment: я вывел переменную в самый верх
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Kafuzma1 frag1;
    Kafuzma2 frag2;
    FragmentTransaction fTrans;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте делал немного иначе логику приложения. Вот как бы получилось: есть родительская активность, в ней контейнер с фрагментами ваших кафизм, и кнопку с счетчиком я бы размещал в активности, потому что при нажатии на кнопку в фрагменте у вас подменяется фрагмент и получается что вам нужно делать одно и тоже действие много-много раз. А в вашем случае я бы лучше делал коммит в каждом case, возможно проблема из-за этого, вообще так выглядит переход из одного фрагмента в другой:

```
Fragment fragment = new tasks();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

код взял из своего проекта. Вообще у вас все должно быть нормально как уже говорил Дмитрий в комментарии.

UPDATE:
пришел в голову еще один вариант, вы можете заменять данные в фрагменте а не создавать кучу фрагментов (а именно 22), это будет более правильно на мой взгляд. Вы просто при нажатии на кнопку в активности посылаете в фрагмент данные о номере кафизмы и в фрагменте уже грузите эту кафизму по номер откуда вы ее получаете.

Comment: Как для новичка мне это все очень сложно понять. Я читал, на форумах, что такие большие текстовые приложения лучше реализовать через фрагменты (быстрее работать). Что я и сделал. Кнопки ведь у каждой кафизмы будут свои (в кафизме1 будет кнопка butKf_2, а вот в кафизме 2 - будет butKf_1 и butKf_3 и т.д. ). А активити одна. Я просто не знаю как по другому можно.

Comment: да, вы правы, фрагменты легче для устройства, но вы ведь создаете 22 фрагмента получается?

Comment: Да, там еще загвоздка была в том, что мне нужно было вставлять разноцветный текст с отступами и обзацами. Я его реализовал через xml и код получился грамоздкий, а если бы я делал через новую активити, то код бы получился гигантский. Я вас правильно понял?
Мне бы вот реализовать onClick. 
Я вот здесь читал
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383052/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83

Comment: у вас кнопка где находится, в разметке фрагмента или активности?

Comment: Да, в фрагменте.
Я не пойму как в коментарий вставить код, я бы показал.

Comment: найдите кнопку по id в классе фрагмента, через findViewById и прилепите клик по ней, у вас сложная конструкция приведена которая с виду выглядит нормально, но может где-то ошибка выше есть, и поэтому все не работает, так же проверьте правильность id кнопки

Comment: Я вас понял, просто у меня там все сложно, когда прописываю findViewById, у меня там становится все красным. 
Можно я вам на почту скину свой код?

Comment: я кажется понял в чем у вас проблема, вы же из фрагмента работаете, а значит вам нужно указать корневой layout, можете бросить на почту код