# Как обратится к разным виджетам в разных ориентациях экрана

Tags: java, android, xml

Проблема в следующем: создал разные `Layout` для разных ориентаций, мне надо, чтобы в зависимости от ориентации присутствовал либо отсутствовал, допустим, 
`TextView`, то есть в вертикальной он есть и должен заполняться данными, а в горизонтальной его нет и он, соответственно, заполняться данными не должен.

---

Как это можно указать в коде? Есть ли какие-нибудь уловки? Или можно только программно узнавать ориентацию и действовать дальше в зависимости от ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай разные фрагменты. И в зависимости от ориентации экрана меняй фрагменты.

[Как заменить фрагмент на фрагмент android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381523/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-android)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать например так:

```
private TextView textView;

...

public void onCreate() {
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if(textView != null) {
        //TextView есть в разметке, делайте с ним, что надо
    } else {
        //TextView нет в разметке, значит ничего сделать с ним вы не сможете
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете узнать ориентацию следующим образом:

```
  if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
           //Действие для портретной ориентации
        else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            //Действие для лендскейпа
```

Соответственно, для другой ориентации Вам необходимо отредактировать `layout.xml`  нужным образом (добавить туда `TextView`, в вашем случае)

Если Вам необходимо загружать туда определённые данные - инициализируйте `TextView` в `Activity`, в котором будете производить проверку.