# Android: разные Activity для разных ориентаций

Tags: android, activity

Всем привет.
Как сделать разные activity для вертикальной и горизонтальной ориентации? (в XML разные типы VIEW)

Comment: Получить программно ориентацию и запустить активити `A` или `B`?..

Answer (score 0):

Такой вопрос уже был в английском сегменте сайта:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode

XML для альтернативной верстки помещается в папки проекта:

res/layout-land – альтернативная верстка для landscape UI

res/layout-port –альтернативная верстка для portrait UI

res/lauout-square – альтернативная верстка для square UI

Comment: Извиняюсь, может чего не понимаю. Но я уже создал в лэйаут-лэнд xml для горизонтальной ориентации. Но как подключить активити другое? Так как айди для разных ориентаций остается одно и то же.

Comment: Традиционно на одну активити можно натягивать несколько разметок. То что, вы хотите (не знаю правда зачем?) можно попробовать сделать через фрагменты. 
Детали по ссылке 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381523/Как-заменить-фрагмент-на-фрагмент-android


Несколько ссылок с материалами по поводу работы со сменой ориентации экрана. Надеюсь, что они будут Вам полезны.
https://habrahabr.ru/post/146632/
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html