# Переход в другое активити при нажатии на элемент CardView. Android

Tags: android

имеется RecyclerView и CardView. Как перейти на другое активити при нажатии на элемент CardView?
Код:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textViewShopName;
        public TextView textViewChainStores;
        public TextView textViewShopAddress;
        public TextView textViewShopModeWork;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewShopName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopName);
            textViewChainStores = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChainStores);
            textViewShopAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopAddress);
            textViewShopModeWork = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopModeWork);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ProductFragment.class);
//                    intent.putExtra("login",login);
//                    intent.putExtra("password",password);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Не видит метод startActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас адаптер прописан не в классе с активностью. Сделайте `ctx.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я про контекст забыл))

Comment: ошибку выдает: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.danilshik.testapplication/com.example.danilshik.testapplication.fragments.ProductFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?/

Comment: может это потому что не активити а фрагмент?

Comment: Да, если у вас `ProductFragment` - `fragment`, то фрагменты вызываются не через интент, а добавляются в заготовленный в активности контейнер через `FragmentTransaction`

Comment: т.е я не могу от фрагмента к другому фрагменту перейти, без активности (Navigation Drawer Activity)?

Comment: Ну вы можете заменить один фрагмент другим в рамках одной активности через `ft.replace(...)`. Почитайте про фрагменты или задайте новый вопрос по существу. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381523/Как-заменить-фрагмент-на-фрагмент-android